# JavaFX - transform from disable to enable button

Tags: java, button, javafx, fxml

### Controller of the father class

this class contains 3 button 'btnSocieta', 'btnUnitaLocali', 'btnReparti'.
The first is enable from default other 2 are disable.
In the stackPane i show the start page where you can find right away.

they have to change state after calling method setEnableBtnUnitaLocale or the other one

```
package View.Controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Creazione implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnSocieta;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnUnitaLocali;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnReparti;

    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        btnUnitaLocali.setDisable(true);
        btnReparti.setDisable(true);

        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/fxml/creazione_societa.fxml"));
            stackPane.getChildren().removeAll();
            stackPane.getChildren().setAll(root);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void switchToSocieta(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/fxml/creazione_societa.fxml"));
        stackPane.getChildren().removeAll();
        stackPane.getChildren().setAll(root);
    }

    public void switchToUnitaLocali(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/fxml/creazione_unitalocale.fxml"));
        stackPane.getChildren().removeAll();
        stackPane.getChildren().setAll(root);
    }

    public void switchToReparti(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    }

    public void setEnableBtnUnitaLocale() {
        
        btnUnitaLocali.setDisable(false);
        System.out.println("setEnableBtnUnitaLocale()");

    }

    public void setEnableBtnReparti() {

        btnReparti.setDisable(false);
    }

}
```

### FXML file menaged by Creazione that have a StackPane that contains CreazioneSocieta

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="View.Controllers.Creazione">
   <top>
      <Pane prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="181.0" layoutY="16.0" minWidth="34.0" prefHeight="17.0" text="&gt;&gt;" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="382.0" layoutY="16.0" text="&gt;&gt;" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnSocieta" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="53.0" layoutY="12.0" onAction="#switchToSocieta" text="Società / Ente" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnUnitaLocali" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="255.0" layoutY="12.0" onAction="#switchToUnitaLocali" text="Unità locali" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnReparti" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="453.0" layoutY="12.0" onAction="#switchToReparti" text="Reparti" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </top>
   <center>
      <StackPane fx:id="stackPane" prefHeight="352.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

### Controller of the FXML file

this controller only scope is to call the method 'setEnableBtnUnitaLocale' that we've see before through method 'salvaSocieta'

```
package View.Controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;


public class CreazioneSocieta implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    JFXButton btnSalva;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        

    }

    public void salvaSocieta(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/View/fxml/main_creazione.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        
        Creazione controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setEnableBtnUnitaLocale();

    }
    
}
```

### FXML File that contains the save button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
   fx:controller="View.Controllers.CreazioneSocieta">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="51.0" layoutY="139.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="93.0"
         text="Ragione Sociale:" />
      <TextField layoutX="153.0" layoutY="135.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="437.0" />
      <Label layoutX="51.0" layoutY="203.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="56.0" text="Indirizzo:" />
      <TextField layoutX="115.0" layoutY="199.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="330.0" />
      <Label layoutX="51.0" layoutY="324.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="56.0" text="Telefono:" />
      <TextField accessibleText="INTEGER" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="320.0" prefHeight="25.0"
         prefWidth="330.0" />
      <Label layoutX="51.0" layoutY="262.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="43.0" text="e-mail:" />
      <TextField layoutX="115.0" layoutY="258.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="330.0" />
      <Label layoutX="467.0" layoutY="203.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="56.0" text="Provincia:" />
      <TextField accessibleText="INTEGER" layoutX="533.0" layoutY="199.0" prefHeight="25.0"
         prefWidth="56.0" />
      <JFXButton onAction="#salvaSocieta" contentDisplay="CENTER" defaultButton="true"
         graphicTextGap="0.0" layoutX="573.0" layoutY="421.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="0.0"
         ripplerFill="#bfbdbd" textFill="WHITE" textOverrun="CLIP">
         <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="37.0" fitWidth="37.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../icons/save_icon.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </graphic>
      </JFXButton>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

### Problem: The 'btnUnitaLocale' doesn't became enable after calling the function 'setEnableBtnUnitaLocale'

Comment: It's not really clear what you're doing in the `salvaSocieta(...)` method. You load the `main_creazione.fxml` file, and call a method on its controller, but since you never actually do anything with the UI you loaded (i.e. you just put it in the variable `root`, and then do nothing) you obviously won't see the result of calling the controller method anywhere.

Comment: i don't really know ho to call the method from a class to an other without creating a new Object of the Creazione class

Comment: The "quick and dirty" approach would just be to pass a reference to the existing `Creazione` instance to the `CreazioneSocieta` controller instance that is created when you load `creazione_societa.fxml`. But really here you should use a [MVC (or similar) design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [MVC approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx). Define a `Model` class that contains the state of the application, with mechanisms to observe the values and respond to them changes. You can use JavaFX Properties to do this easily (see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm) or the "Bindings and Observable Values" section of [this](https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/elements/), and links from there)

```
public class Model {

    private final BooleanProperty societySaved = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    public BooleanProperty societySavedProperty() {
        return societySaved ;
    }

    public final boolean isSocietySaved() {
        return societySavedProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setSocietySaved(boolean societySaved) {
        societySavedProperty().set(societySaved);
    }


    // similarly for other properties as needed
}
```

In your `Creazione` controller class, define a field for the model and bind the state of the button to the state in the model:

```
public class Creazione {

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnSocieta;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnUnitaLocali;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnReparti;

    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane;

    private Model model ;

    public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model ;
        btnUnitaLocali.disableProperty().bind(model.societySavedProperty().not());
        // similarly for other buttons and properties in the model
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        //btnUnitaLocali.setDisable(true);
        //btnReparti.setDisable(true);

        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/fxml/creazione_societa.fxml"));
            stackPane.getChildren().removeAll();
            stackPane.getChildren().setAll(root);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // ... (further modifications to methods shown later)



    // these are not needed
    // public void setEnableBtnUnitaLocale() {
        
    //     btnUnitaLocali.setDisable(false);
    //     System.out.println("setEnableBtnUnitaLocale()");

    // }

    // public void setEnableBtnReparti() {

    //     btnReparti.setDisable(false);
    // }

}
```

Similarly, in your other controllers, define a reference to the model and update the property. For example:

```
public class CreazioneSocieta  {

    private Model model ;

    public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }


    public void salvaSocieta(ActionEvent event) {
        
        model.setSocietySaved(true);

    }
    
}
```

Now, in your application code, you need to create a `Model` instance and when you load the initial
view, pass the model to the controller:

```
Model model = new Model();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/View/fxml/main_creazione.fxml"));
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        
Creazione controller = loader.getController();
controller.setModel(model);

Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
// etc.
```

Finally, back in your `Creazione` class, be sure to pass the same model instance to the other controllers. For example:

```
public class Creazione {

    // existing code ...

    public void switchToSocieta(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/View/fxml/creazione_societa.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        CreazioneSocieta controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setModel(model);

        stackPane.getChildren().removeAll();
        stackPane.getChildren().setAll(root);
    }
}
```

For better decoupling of the controllers, in particular in the context of switching scene, study [this example](https://gist.github.com/james-d/bae73788a9b881cf9358cbf2d842f554).

Comment: can you pls review my latest answer ty so much for your correction but there is a little problem that i couldn't solve if not like that

Answer (score 0):

## I ended up doing this:

#### This is the method you can find in ViewController

```
public void switchToCreazione(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    CreazioneModel creazioneModel = new CreazioneModel();

    FXMLLoader loader = 
  new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/View/fxml/main_creazione.fxml"));

    Parent root = loader.load();
    Creazione creazione = loader.getController();

    creazione.setCreazioneModel(creazioneModel);

    stackPane.getChildren().removeAll();
    stackPane.getChildren().setAll(root);
}
```

### This is the method you can find in the preview answer

```
public void setCreazioneModel(CreazioneModel creazioneModel) {
    this.creazioneModel = creazioneModel;

    try {
        switchToSocieta();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    this.btnUnitaLocali
        .disableProperty()
        .bind(creazioneModel.societaSavedProperty().not());
    this.btnReparti
        .disableProperty()
        .bind(creazioneModel.unitaLocaleSavedProperty().not());}
```

### This is the method setModel in CreazioneModel class

```
public void setCreazioneModel(CreazioneModel creazioneModel) {
    this.creazioneModel = creazioneModel;

    try {
        switchToSocieta();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    this.btnUnitaLocali
        .disableProperty()
        .bind(creazioneModel.societaSavedProperty().not());
    this.btnReparti
        .disableProperty()
        .bind(creazioneModel.unitaLocaleSavedProperty().not());}
```

## Warning

i couldn't call switchToSocieta in the initialize method of Creazione because it wont have the Model correctly initialized

Comment: Creating a new model instance is almost certainly an error.